# Multiple threads calling the same objects function simultaneously. Can it cause problems?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose I have the following C# class

```
class MyClass
{
    private int _i;
    private object _locker = new object();

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var b = 2;

        // some work that depends on b being 2

        lock(_locker)
        {
            _i = 3;
        }

        // some more work

        b = -1;

        // some more work
    }
}
```

And I use it this way,

```
//Usage:

var myobject = new MyClass();
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => myobject.DoSomething())).Start();
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => myobject.DoSomething())).Start();
```

Can the following sequence happen?

```
Thread 1 is halfway through its work.
Thread 2 just starts. Sets b = 2. 
Thread 1 sets b = -1. 
Thread 2 is confused because it expected b to be 2 but its -1.
```

The important point is that `b` is a local variable. Will the two threads get access to the same instance of b? I understand that for the instance variable `_i`, this will happen. Hence the `lock` construct for that. But am not sure whether I need to do locking for local variables as well.

Comment: `b` is local and therefore unique to each thread.

Comment: If `_i` is just assigned with the same values twice why don't you consider moving the assignment in a non-concurrent piece of code before starting the threads? (or when they finish)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The local variable will be put on the stack when a caller enters the method `DoSomething()`. Each thread operates on a separate stack and will get its own unique local variable.

This part from [Wikipedia for thread local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) applies to C# threading as well:

> In other words, data in a static or global variable is normally always
>   located at the same memory location, when referred to by threads from
>   the same process. Variables on the stack however are local to threads,
>   because each thread has its own stack, residing in a different memory
>   location.

Comment: I know in my example the `b` is a primitive type. But suppose `b` is an object of some class. And I am modifying its property. Now `b`  being a reference type, will it still be on the stack local to each thread? I thought reference type objects were stored in the heap memory which is shared by all threads...

Comment: @Amith: If you create the object within the method the *object reference* is still stored on the stack while the object itself will be allocated on the heap. Fundamentally this does not change anything since each thread has its own object reference to a different object on the heap.

Comment: What if b was a reference type and was passed to the method as a method parameter?